# Find volume of region using change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, solid-geometry

I want to find the volume of the region $R$ that lies between

$$z= x^2 + y^2, \quad z= 4(x^2 + y^2), \quad z = 1, \quad z = 4$$

Using the transformation
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{r}{t}\cos(\theta)\\
y &= \frac{r}{t}\sin(\theta)\\
z &= r^2
\end{align}

Now, I understand how to do this problem(finding the jacobian, plugging in the transformation, doing the triple integral), but what I don't understand is how to find the bounds for r,t and theta. Is there a general method on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your region is as follows:

$r\in[2,4]$, $\theta\in[0..2\pi]$, $z\in[2..4]$

[image]

Comment: er why isn't r from 0.5 to 1? (plugging in z=1 and z = 4 into the equations)

Comment: and what about t? what's t?

Comment: @praks5432: Which coordinates are you using? Cartesian $(x,y,z)$? Cylindrical $(r,\theta,z)$? Or Spherical $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$? It looks to me that you are using the second coordinates, so we have 3 coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ not 4 coordinates. I mean that existing another parameter, say $t$, is meaningless here.

Comment: Beautiful! $\quad +1 \;\ddot\smile\;$ I hope to see you tonight before I go to bed (my time that is, but morning your time!)

Comment: @amWhy: I came here but seems you went to the Heaven. Have a peaceful colored sleep my dear Amy.

Comment: Hello, Babak! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Hi dear friend. I was not here.

Comment: Well you've been workin' with other tasks. Life apart from Math.se!

Comment: @amWhy: Unfortunately or fortunately Yes! Life goes on and it needs more attention. Like a wild function, it rules us. :-)